# Как вставить массив в массив в Python?

Tags: python, массивы

Подскажите пожалуйста как вставить массив в массив в Python? Есть метод, который вставляет элемент в массив, но не понимаю как передать вместо элемента целый массив.

```
class DynamicArray(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.n = 0
    self.capacity = 1
    self.arr = self.make_array(self.capacity)

def insert(self, item, index):
    if index < 0 or index > self.n:
        print("Индекс выходит за границы массива")
        return
    if self.n == self.capacity:
        self._resize(2 * self.capacity)
    for i in range(self.n - 1, index - 1, -1):
        self.arr[i + 1] = self.arr[i]
    self.arr[index + 1] = item
    self.n += 1
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос трактуется по-разному. Уточните: вам нужно, чтобы массив переданных значений распаковался в ваш `self.arr` или чтобы внутри `self.arr` оказался вложенный массив?

Comment: `old[:x] + new + old[:x]` - можно например, так

Comment: Чтобы внутри self.arr был вложенный массив

Comment: Что такое "массив" в Python?

Comment: {{[[]]}{[[]]}{[[]]}}